# What does `true = false` mean in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq

[I am not sure this is appropriate for stack overflow, but there are many other Coq questions here so perhaps someone can help.]

I am working through the following from http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/Basics.html#lab28 (just below where Case is introduced).  Note that I am a complete beginner at this, and am working at home - I am not a student.

```
Theorem andb_true_elim1 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> b = true.
Proof.
  intros b c H.
  destruct b.
  Case "b = true".
    reflexivity.
  Case "b = false".
    rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

and I am looking at what the rewrite does:

```
  Case := "b = false" : String.string
  c : bool
  H : andb false c = true
  ============================
   false = true
```

then `rewrite <- H.` is applied:

```
  Case := "b = false" : String.string
  c : bool
  H : andb false c = true
  ============================
   false = andb false c
```

and it's clear how the proof will succeed.

I can see how in terms of manipulating symbols in a mechanical way I am arriving at a proof.   That's fine.  But I am disturbed by the "meaning".  In particular, how can I have `false = true` in the middle of a proof?

It seems like I am making some kind of argument with contradictions, but I am not sure what.  I feel like I have been blindly following rules and have somehow arrived at a point where I am typing nonsense.

What am I *doing* above?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: You could try using: [`discriminate`](http://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/grupos/mf/man/Coq/node.1.2.8.html). (I see it's an old post)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally, when you do a case analysis in a theorem prover, a lot of the cases boil down to "cannot happen".  For example, if you are proving some fact about the integers, you may need to do a case analysis of whether the integer `i` is positive, zero, or negative.  But there may be other hypotheses lying around in your context, or perhaps some part of your goal, that is contradictory with one of the cases.  You may know from a previous assertion, for example, that `i` can never be negative.

However Coq is not that smart.  So you still have to go through the mechanics of actually showing that the two contradictory hypotheses can be glued together into a proof of absurdity and hence a proof of your theorem.

Think about it like in a computer program:

```
switch (k) {
  case X:
    /* do stuff */
    break;
  case Y:
    /* do other stuff */
    break;
  default:
    assert(false, "can't ever happen");
}
```

The `false = true` goal is the "can't ever happen".  But you can't just assert your way out in Coq.  You actually have to put down a proof term.

So above, you have to prove the absurd goal `false = true`.  And the only thing you have to work with is the hyothesis `H: andb false c = true`.  A moment's thought will show you that actually this is an absurd hypothesis (because `andb false y` reduces to false for any `y` and hence cannot possibly be true).  So you bang on the goal with the only thing at your disposal (namely `H`) and your new goal is `false = andb false c`.

So you apply an absurd hypothesis trying to achive an absurd goal.  And lo and behold you end up with something you can actually show by reflexivity. Qed.

**UPDATE**  Formally, here's what's going on.

Recall that every inductive definition in Coq comes with an induction principle.  Here are the types of the induction principles for equality and the `False` proposition (as opposed to the term `false` of type `bool`):

```
Check eq_ind.
eq_ind
  : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Prop),
    P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
Check False_ind.
False_ind
 : forall P : Prop, False -> P
```

That induction principle for `False` says that if you give me a proof of `False`, I can give you a proof of any proposition `P`.

The induction principle for `eq` is more complicated.  Let's consider it confined to `bool`.  And specifically to `false`.  It says:

```
Check eq_ind false.
eq_ind false
 : forall P : bool -> Prop, P false -> forall y : bool, false = y -> P y
```

So if you start with some proposition `P(b)` that depends on a boolean `b`, and you have a proof of `P(false)`, then for any other boolean `y` that is equal to `false`, you have a proof of `P(y)`.

This doesn't sound terribly exiciting, but we can apply it to any proposition `P` that we want.  And we want a particularly nasty one.

```
Check eq_ind false (fun b : bool => if b then False else True).
eq_ind false (fun b : bool => if b then False else True)
 : (fun b : bool => if b then False else True) false ->
   forall y : bool,
   false = y -> (fun b : bool => if b then False else True) y
```

Simplifying a bit, what this says is `True -> forall y : bool, false = y -> (if y then False else True)`.

So this wants a proof of `True` and then some boolean `y` that we get to pick.  So let's do that.

```
Check eq_ind false (fun b : bool => if b then False else True) I true.
eq_ind false (fun b : bool => if b then False else True) I true
 : false = true -> (fun b : bool => if b then False else True) true
```

And here we are: `false = true -> False`.

Combining with what we know about the induction principle for `False`, we have:  if you give me a proof of `false = true`, I can prove any proposition.

So back to `andb_true_elim1`.  We have a hypothesis `H` that is `false = true`.  And we want to prove some kind of goal.  As I've shown above, there exists a proof term that turns proofs of `false = true` into proofs of anything you want.  So in particular `H` is a proof of `false = true`, so you can now prove any goal you want.

The tactics are basically machinery that builds the proof term.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense, but what i still don't understand is how combining two things that are both "wrong" or "absurd" somehow makes things "right".  i can see that it works - the proof comes out - but why should it work?  why is it that one absurd thing somehow cancels another absurd thing, and will it always work that way?  it seems like there is something "deeper" that i am still missing?  is it that i am assuming something contradictory and then showing that it is indeed contradictory?

Comment: @andrewcooke What you have here is not two wrong things, but two contradictory things. Your hypotheses *taken as a whole* are self-contradictory. more precisely, your hypotheses as a whole imply a false statement, and therefore you can prove anything (including your goal) from these hypotheses. The only way way hypotheses can imply a false statement is if there is no way for the hypotheses to be true.

Comment: so i could just as well type "Admit." instead of the rewrite and the proof would be equally as good?

Comment: @andrew cooke: "admit" is not a "real" proof.  All it does is introduce an axiom that is precisely the thing you are trying to prove.  It's a way to leave holes to be proved later.  You can however complete the branch via `exact H`

Comment: if i cannot use Admit then i am doing *something* with the rewrite.  yet when i say that i am cancelling contradictions @Giles corrects me (i think).  either the rewrite is doing something useful, and in some way i don't understand "two wrongs are making a right" or i am simply forcing Coq to stop complaining, in which case Admit should be acceptable.  obviously i am wrong here, but perhaps the above shows my confusion?

Comment: ouch.  ok, so the real answer means i need to think :o)  ok, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 8):

`true = false` is a statement equating two different boolean values. Since those values are different this statement is clearly not provable (in the empty context).

Considering your proof: you arrive at the stage where the goal is `false = true`, so clearly you won't be able to prove it... but the thing is that your context (assumptions) are also contradictory. This often happens for instance when you do case-analysis and one of the cases is contradictory with your other assumptions.

Comment: thanks.  as with the other reply, this makes sense, but i still don't grasp why two contradictory things somehow "cancel each other out".  i can see that it happens, but it feels like there must be some underlying reason "why"...?  do contradictions always appear in pairs?  if so, what is the principle that makes this so?

Comment: Correction: It's clearly not provable _in the empty context_.

Comment: @RobinGreen: indeed, that's what I had in mind. Clarified the answered; thanks.

Comment: Think about this way: you need to prove that your goal (G) follows from you hypothesis (H): `H->G`. You hypothesis happens to be always False (you can prove it that `true!=false` based on bool's definition). So what you trying to prove is: `False -> G`. This is always True by the definition of implication.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but I want to clarify some of the intuition behind Lambdageek's answer (in case someone finds this)

I noticed that the key point seems to be that we define a function `F:bool->Prop` with different values at each point (ie. `true => True` and `false => False`). However it can easily be shown from the induction principle for equality `eq_ind` the intuitive idea (this is in fact the "[Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles)" way of defining equality) that

```
forall P:bool -> Prop, forall x,y:bool, (x = y) -> (P x) -> (P y),
```

But this would mean that from `true=false` and `I:True`, we can conclude `False`.

Another fundamental property we are using here is the ability to define `F`, which is given by the recursion principle for bool, `bool_rect`:

```
forall P:bool -> Type, P true -> P false -> (forall b:bool, P b)
```

by choosing `P := (fun b:bool => Prop)`, then we get

```
(bool_rect P) : Prop -> Prop -> (bool -> Prop),
```

where we input `True` and `False` to get our function `F`.

If we put this all together, we would get

```
(eq_ind true (bool_rect (fun b => Prop) True False) I false) : true = false -> False
```

**It is also worth pointing out that Coq takes induction/recursion principles like `eq_ind` or `bool_rect` as axioms that *define* the identity and boolean types.**

Answer (score 0):

The normal, human, way of proving this is to say that since the hypothesis is not matched in this case, we do not need to prove the sequel. And in Coq, there is a way for expressing that. This is through a tactic named `inversion`.

Here is an example:

```
Theorem absurd_implies_absurd : 
  true = false -> 1 = 2.
Proof.
  intros H.
  inversion H.
  Qed.
```

The first step let `H` be the hypothesis `true = false`, and therefore the goal to prove is `1 = 2`.

The `inversion H` step will automatically prove the goal! Exactly what we wanted, magic!

To understand this magic, we turn to the documentation of what `inversion` means.

To a beginner (like me), the official documentation for inversion is terse and cryptic to read, [here](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs195x/current/sf/html/MoreCoq.html) is a much better explanation of it. Search for the keyword inversion on the page and you will find this:

If `c` and `d` are different constructors, then the hypothesis `H` is contradictory. That is, a false assumption has crept into the context, and this means that any goal whatsoever is provable! In this case, inversion H marks the current goal as completed and pops it off the goal stack.

This expresses exactly what we wanted. The only issue is that this is ahead of the book's plan. Of course, rewriting `true` to `false` will work. The issue is not that it doesn't work, the issue is that it is just not what we wanted.